adding signature to letter using moderncv package
I'm writing a cover letter using the moderncv package and want to include a signature after the name sign off. E.g.

Yours sincerely,
signature.png
Myname

Attached is my MWE.
%
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}      
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{black}                            

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage{sans}
% adjust the page margins
% \usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}

% personal data
\name{name}{}
\email{gmail}
\phone[mobile]{9998 9999}               
% \address{Village, City - State, Country}


\begin{document}

\recipient{To}{The Teacher-In-Charge, \\
               Department of Computer Application,\\ 
               Full Address (State)}
\date{\today}
\opening{\textbf{Sub: Application for the post of Guest Lecturer (Computer Application) with reference advertisement: XXXX/XX, dated 04-03-2022.}}
\closing{Yours Sincerely, \vspace{-1em} }
% \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{Signature_b.png} 



% \enclosure[Enclosed (Marksheets/Certificates)]{
%               \\ 1. SSLC (Admit/MarkSheet/Certificate)
%                  \hspace{0.0em} 5. GATE (2016) \hspace{2em} 9. Identity-Proof (Voter-Id)\\
%                  2. Diploma (MarkSheet/Certificate)
%                  \hspace{1.8em} 6. SLET (2021) \hspace{1.9em} 10. Resume\\        
%                  3. B.Tech (MarkSheet/Certificate)
%                  \hspace{2.3em} 7. UGC-NET (2022) \hspace{-0.1em} \\
%                  4. M.Tech (MarkSheet/Certificate)
%                  \hspace{2.1em} 8. Caste Certificate \\
%                  }
\makelettertitle



Respected Sir,
\\
%references such as what and how you got this information
\vspace{1em}
With reference to the subject as cited above, I XXXXXXX, would like to apply for the said post. I found the said reference through a job portal site and information provided in the university official website.\\

%narrate why you want to apply
\vspace{1em}

\vspace{1em}


blah blah give me a job mate 

%conclusion
\vspace{1em}
I am sure that my proven ability to manage and maintain the highest decorum as Lecturer will be of utmost beneficial for the institution, and I too believe I can make a significant contribution to the institution as well as to the nation. \\

\vspace{1em}
I look forward to an opportunity to serve as a Guest Lecturer in the Dept. of Computer Application, under "University Name" and be considered for the above-said post.

\vspace{0.5cm}


\makeletterclosing
\includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image} \par

\end{document}


The typical structure of letter generation is quite odd. This goes both for the traditional letter class as well as using moderncv. Why? Because there's a whole bunch of definitions in the preamble (\name, \email, \phone, \address, \recipient, \date, \opening, \closing, \enclosure, ...) that is just printed in the main document with some commensurate macro (\makelettertitle, \makeletterclosing, ...).
The easiest way to get what you want is to just set the closing manually:
% ...

I look forward to an opportunity to serve as a Guest Lecturer in the Dept. of Computer Application, under "University Name" and be considered for the above-said post.

%\makeletterclosing

Yours sincerely,

\includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image}




Alternatively, you can use the \signature macro, which assumes you're passing a signature as an image. \signature takes two arguments. The first is a scaling factor and the second is the image name. So, using \signature{0.25}{example-image} together with \makeletterclosing you'll see

You'll have to fiddle with the scaling factor of your actual signature as it doesn't provide options to set the actual height. Well, that's not actually true, because you could use
\signature{1,height=4\baselineskip}{example-image}

This works with the implementation of the \signature macro (which changes the scale and then sets the height), but it looks awkward in terms of the user interface.
